# netdata monitoring - unable to install mysql plugin

Tags: netdata

I can't find instruction how to install the python.d plugins for netdata - I want to use the mysql plugin - but I have no such configuration file, and the /etc/netdata/python.d/ folder is empty.

how can I install the missing plug-ins so I can configure the mysql monitoring.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked out the documentation? This may help: https://docs.netdata.cloud/collectors/python.d.plugin/mysql/

*(Edit for additional context)*

All plugins (aka collectors) are installed by default—you don't need to install the MySQL collector.

To enable the collector, navigate to the `/etc/netdata directory` and use the `edit-config` script.

```
cd /etc/netdata
sudo ./edit-config python.d/mysql.conf
```

Configure the collector job according to your setup, and then [restart Netdata](https://docs.netdata.cloud/docs/getting-started/#start-stop-and-restart-netdata) and refresh your browser once it's running again.

Other resources about editing config files:

[configuration guide](https://docs.netdata.cloud/docs/configuration-guide/#configuration-guide)

[basics of configuring Netdata](https://docs.netdata.cloud/docs/step-by-step/step-04/#use-edit-config-to-open-netdataconf)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't show how to install it. I think I am missing one step before getting to this document.